react-navigation navigate function causing unhandled exception 'RCTComponentViewRegistry: Attempt to query unregistered component
I am receiving an event from a react native webview and in that event attempting to navigate to a different stack.
However the app crashes every time with the following
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
 reason: 'RCTComponentViewRegistry: Attempt to query unregistered component.

Am i doing something wrong, do i need to dispatch the event to some main thread or something?
Any thoughts greatly welcomed, code below
   <WebView
      ref={webViewRef}
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
      webviewDebuggingEnabled
      style={{flex: 1}}
      source={{uri: url}}
      onMessage={event => {
        console.log(`Received a message from webview:${JSON.stringify(event.nativeEvent)}`);
        const data = JSON.parse(
          event.nativeEvent.data,
         ) as MyEventType;
         if (data.type === 'ended') {
           onEventComplete();
         }
       }
     />

  const onEventComplete = () => {
    navigation.push('SomeScreen', {autoRecord: true});
  };


Navigation is fine on a button press but i would like to automatically navigate when an event occurs



package
version




@react-navigation/native
6.1.17


@react-navigation/native-stack
6.9.26


react-native-screens
3.32.0


react-native-gesture-handler
2.17.1


react-native-reanimated
^3.14.0


react-native
0.74.3


node
22.3.0


yarn
4.3.1




Works fine on Android FYI, which i guess makes sense seing as its a IOS native specific exception
